# Is this series proposition even true?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\displaystyle\sum a_n$ a positive terms series. We define the following sequence $(q_n)$:

$$(q_n) = (1-a_1)(1-a_2)...(1-a_n)$$

Prove that $\displaystyle\sum a_n$ converges if and only if $(q_n)$ converges to a positive number.

So I got this from the textbook we're using on single-variable calculus, but I can't convince this is true. Is as simple as taking:

$$a_1 = 3$$
$$a_n = \frac{1}{n^2}, n \geq 2$$

Which converges, but $\forall n\geq 1, (q_n) \leq 0$, so it wouldn't make sense that $(q_n)$ converges to a positive number. What's the trick here?

Comment: Your textbook probably insists that $1-a_i$ be positive, too. If not, it should.

Comment: It doesn't. With that the proposition becomes clear.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hint. 
$$\log(1 + x) \sim x$$
as $x\to 0$. Can you use it?

Comment: It might help to point out that $\log(q_n)=\log(1+(-a_1))+\log(1+(-a_2))+...+\log(1+(-a_n))\sim -\sum a_{i}$.  So $q_{n}\sim e^{-\sum a_{i}}$.

Comment: Although this seems useful and may help achieve a proof, I still feel confused about the supposed counterexample I presented.